# Is it possible to use MLFlow and H2o.ai sparkling water in a Scala based project?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h2o, sparkling-water, mlflow

I'm solving a Scala data science problem in Intellij using maven. I noticed that MLFlow spark (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mlflow/mlflow-spark/1.5.0) is dependent on scala 2.12 while h2o.ai sparkling water is dependent on scala 2.11 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ai.h2o/sparkling-water-core). Is there any way to use both of these together using Scala?

Comment: well formatted posts get better responses, see here for how to format your links https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You can track progress of introducing Scala 2.12 support in Sparkling Water with the JIRA ticket [SW-1846](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/SW-1846).